# is it possible to use ExtJS with backbone.js?

Tags: extjs, backbone.js

i have a backbone.js api i want to use in an ExtJS app.

Extjs has a very flexible model and proxy system.  but i cant see a good way to consume backbone.js models.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

extjs is a heavyweight solution, and extjs has full support for mvc architecture; backbone is a very lightweight solution, both of which generally do not need to co-exist it.